# Secular Concerts in a Shul?

Tags: halacha, synagogue, music

Here's a softball. :)

Does the Seridei Eish, [HaRav Yechiel Yaakov Weinberg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yechiel_Yaakov_Weinberg) zt"l permit the performance of a secular concert in a synagogue?

Comment: Why specifically the Seridei Eish?

Comment: His opinion came up in another related discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The Seridei Eish even spoke about having a classical music concert in a synagogue (when Germany banned Jews from attending concert houses)." ולפי"ז בודאי שיש איסור לעשות קונצרטים של חול בביהכ"נ. ואף שבאשכנז רבים מאד בין היראים שהולכים לקונצרטים של חול אפשר שסומכים בזה על שיטת ההר"מ דאינו אסור אלא במשתה או למי שרגיל בו וכמבואר באו"ח סי' תק"ס הנ"ל ועיי"ש בטור ובב"י. אבל באמת מסקנת הפוסקים לאסור, ואם אין בידנו למחות נגד אלה שהולכים לקונצרטים משום שהוא דבר שאינו משמע בארץ אשכנז עכ"פ אין לנו להתיר בביהכ"נ (שרידי אש א"ח טז:כ" – Yirmeyahu

[Going to classical music concert](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1352/going-to-non-jewish-concert)

Yirmiyahu, I am confused. Are you checking if we are reading your posts? Because I do try to read everything that I see you have written.

Comment: I appreciate the kind words about trying to read what I've written. The Seridie Eish's position had been brought up in a way that I felt implied his opinion was different than what it was. I thought this would be a way to present the issue in a way that furthers the primary format of the site rather than continue in the comment section (he writes in the comment section... :) )