# Is it disrespectful to listen to secular music in the same room where there is a Tanakh book?

Tags: jewish-books, music, secular-culture

My question might sound stupid or weird, but my house is small and I keep my Tanakh book in my bedroom, and one day there was people in the other room so I stayed in my bedroom and turned on the secular music in my phone, I felt like I am disrespecting the presence of the Tanakh in the room.

And today I was listening to secular music but through headphones in my laptop.

I want to know if this was disrespectful. I don't know if listening to secular music is allowed anyway.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5794/5323 (permissibility of secular music); http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1405/5323 (secular music in a synagogue)

Comment: Not addressing your question but possibly of interest: https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/hashoneh-halachos/1047-sefarim-room/

Comment: whatever the answer may be,but lets say the answer is no,wouldn't it be worse for you to hear it than an inanimate object.