# Performing for a mixed concert

Tags: halacha, music, performance-entertainment, gender

One finds orthodox performers who sing for mixed-gender audiences (eg [recently](https://www.ynetnews.com/culture/article/h1k4x9nch))

However, one also finds achronim who call this [assur](https://anash.org/did-the-rebbe-allow-separate-seating/).

I'm curious for a bit more explanation of the sources/reasonings behind the two positions. (Obviously Gemaras like [Sukkah 51a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.51a) discussing the temple balcony are probably central, but I'm interested specifically in how both positions apply that precedent here, and which contemporaries speak about the issue.)

A previous question didn't address gender aspect specifically - [Going to classical music concert](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1352/going-to-classical-music-concert).