# Is it Asur to watch violent sports?

Tags: halacha, sport-athletics, performance-entertainment

Is it [Asur](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/591) to watch violent sports like boxing or [UFC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Fighting_Championship), or some of the horrific videos of war footage that can be found online (which were pointed out to me, and to which I won't link here) for entertainment?

Comment: You might want to link to some page describing UFC. I, for one, had never heard of it, though I may, of course, be in a small minority. Also, do you have any reason for thinking it may be _asur_? I mean, why do you ask?

Comment: ... or [NFL football](http://adderabbi.blogspot.com/2005/01/offensive-lines-why-football-makes-me.html)?

Comment: @IsaacMoses Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18721.

Comment: also related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15915/5

Comment: @msh210 done...

Comment: @IsaacMoses, or [hockey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fighting_in_ice_hockey).

Answer (score 4):

From a responsum of R. Yitzchok Abadi ([Ohr Yitzchok vol. 1 YD §26](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1525&pgnum=297)) it would seem to be prohibited on the basis of an opinion in the Talmud with regards to images forbidden to gaze upon ([Meg. 28a](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.28a.15?with=all&lang=bi)). Additionally, according to his presentation of Rambam ([AZ 10:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foreign_Worship_and_Customs_of_the_Nations.10.4?with=all&lang=bi)) it would certainly be prohibited to watch combat sports which is behavior that goes against Jewish ethos.

Comment: @ezra I'd assume so too. Any reason it wouldn't/shouldn't?

Comment: It seems like the OP asked for a reason for it to be asur — so yes, we found you a reason. Nonetheless, +1. Also, obviously, someone dedicated to Judaism and Torah study wouldn’t waste his time with such stuff